# Why does the countdown order change in this loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, innerhtml

I am completely new to Javascript and have been trying to learn while loops. There is one particular example that confuses me, however, and that I can´t wrap my mind around.

This is my code:

```js
function doItAgain (message) { 
    var count = 5;
    while(count > 0) {  
        substance.innerHTML = count + "<br>" + substance.innerHTML;
        count = count - 1;
    }

    alert("done");
}
```

So my question is, why is it that when I place the substance.innerHTML tag after the line break I get a countdown beginning with 1, and when I place it before it begins with 5?

I know its probably a silly question but it would be of tremendous help if you could guide me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be better If you would give executable code directly. `count` goes like '5,4,3,2,1,0' when it becomes 0, it does not pass inside the while block. It should not start from 1. try `console.log(count)` inside while loop

Comment: If I told you to write the numbers 5,4,3,2,1 below each other on a page, what would be at the top? If I then told you to write the same numbers, still starting at 5, above each other, what would it look like? The lesson here is that programs do as they are coded.

Comment: That's the point where you should set a breakpoint inside your loop and just debug it...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `count + "<br>" + substance.innerHTML` you place the new count, on top of the previous counters (you take `counter=2`  for example, put 2, and than what that was before `3 4 5`)

And when you use `substance.innerHTML + "<br>" + count` you first put what was first, which is `5 4 3` and than add count.

```js
let substance = document.getElementById('myDiv');
function doItAgain () { 
    var count = 5;
    while(count > 0) {  
        substance.innerHTML = substance.innerHTML + "<br>" +count;
        count = count - 1;
    }

    console.log("done");
}
doItAgain()
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify what your html, specifically the part regarding "substance.innerHTML"?
Am I correct in assuming "substance" is the class name of a div?

I think your assignment line is incorrect. The line:

```
substance.innerHTML = count + "<br>" + substance.innerHTML;
```

You're running mathematical logic on items that can't be summed together.
By the time your code has reached that line these are the current values:

count = 5 (number)
< br > = an html tag (string)
substance.innerHTML =  (like a string?)

So I think what might be happening is that in one instance, Javascript is stopping at the 
 tag and no including the "substance.innerHTML" in the logic.
And in the second case, it's including the "substance.innnerHTML" in the logic, and still ignoring the 
 after.

I can't really test your code, as I'm not sure what substance.innerHTML is referring to.
Let me know if that answers your problem. :)

Comment: If you use the `+` operator on multiple values and any of those values is a string, JS will do string concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Ah! Right! Thanks for correcting me.
That is really good to know.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. What I´m trying to do  with innerHTML (according to what I´ve learned so far at least) is modify the text  of an html <p> tag through js.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it in terms of what everything equals after each trip (iteration) through your loop. First, I'll show what each iteration will look like, if you're setting `substance.innerHTML = count + "<br>" + substance.innerHTML`:

**Before first time the loop is run**

```
count = 5
substance.innerHTML = ""
```

**After Iteration #1**

```
count = 4
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>"
```

**After Iteration #2**

```
count = 3
substance.innerHTML = "4<br>5<br>"
```

**After Iteration #3**

```
count = 2
substance.innerHTML = "3<br>4<br>5<br>"
```

**After Iteration #4**

```
count = 1
substance.innerHTML = "2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>"
```

**After Iteration #5**

```
count = 0
substance.innerHTML = "1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>"
```

Since you're putting the count *before* everything you set in `substance.innerHTML` already, each time through the loop, you end up with something that looks like it's counting up from `1` to `5`.

If instead you're setting `substance.innerHTML = substance.innerHTML + count + "<br>"`:

**After Iteration #1**

```
count = 4
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>"
```

**After Iteration #2**

```
count = 3
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>4<br>"
```

**After Iteration #3**

```
count = 2
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>4<br>3<br>"
```

**After Iteration #4**

```
count = 1
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>4<br>3<br>2<br>"
```

**After Iteration #5**

```
count = 0
substance.innerHTML = "5<br>4<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>"
```

Since you're putting the count *after* everything you set in substance.innerHTML already, each time through the loop, you end up with something that looks like it's counting down from 5 to 1.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation really helped!